# Why does Yarn sometimes ping pong between how it represents versions?

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

We have a React project that is using Yarn for package management. I notice that Yarn sometimes tweaks versions in the `yarn.lock` file even though nothing is changing. For example, when I run `yarn install`, it wants to make the change from:

```
yarn@^1.21.1:
```

to:

```
yarn@1.21.1, yarn@^1.21.1:
```

I don't quite understand why since the versions are the same. It flip-flops on this change quite often and it just depends on what packages we're installing. This example is for the `yarn` package itself, but it does this with a few different things.

Does anyone have any insight into why this is happening? Is it an issue with one developer's setup vs. another developer's setup? It's incredibly annoying because every time I sync my branch, run a `yarn install`, it wants to make changes to our lock file when I don't think it should be doing this.

Edit:
We also have this in our `package.json` file:

```
"resolutions": {
  "yarn": "1.21.1"
}
```

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but we use [`yarn-deduplicate`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn-deduplicate) to resolve similar issues.

Comment: I ran `yarn-deduplicate` but it didn't change anything in our `yarn.lock` file, unfortunately. It looks like we were able to resolve this by doing a `yarn clean` (or completely removing the `node_modules` folders) and re-running `yarn install` resolved a bunch of weird issues. Will try this going forward...